# What is the best way to check if the device has Internet access?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, navigator

I want to check if the device has **internet access**. From the official cordova documentation:

This code, is only to get the `connection type`

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}

checkConnection();
```

But how can I check if the device really have internet access? That is, because it may be that the device is connected to a router using a WiFi connection type, but that it has no access to internet but only local access. In this case the `checkConnection();` will return: `WiFi connection`.

Or that is connected to a 3G network phone operator, but the user does not have sufficient credits for the internet. In this case the `checkConnection();` will return: `Cell 3G connection`

But in both cases the user have not a real internet access eventhough if connected.

The only thing that I think is to ping google or another server to check if there really has internet access, in the case of `states[networkState] != No network connection`

Or do you think `navigator.onLine` can run on all devices (Android, iOS, BlackBery 10?

I hope I have expressed well, my English really sucks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm... here is a discussion http://iswwwup.com/t/f3e5374b74ca/android-cordova-plugin-to-detect-internet-connection.html

And the solution they mentioned...

A function to test this address to check if the device has access to internet would look like this :

```
function testInternet(win,fail){
    $.get("http://www.google.fr/blank.html").done(win).fail(fail);
}
Or ,

function testInternet(win,fail){
    $.ajax({
         url:"http://www.google.fr/blank.html",
         timeout:5000,   //timeout to 5s
         type: "GET",
         cache: false
       }).done(win).fail(fail); 
}
```

Comment: One last thing, how can I modify this script to throw an `alert` saying if there is internet access in case of `win`?

Comment: this might help : testInternet( function() { alert('Has Internet Connectivity');}, function() { alert('Has No Internet');});

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin that helps you to do that:
[Network information](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information)

try it with a test function to an URL that test your request if it fails then you do somthing else, as many answers explained here, or use

```
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
function onOnline() {  // Handle the online event}

document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
function onOffline() {  // Handle the offline event}
```

Remember to wrap these functions inside a `document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {}, false);`

Comment: The network information only test whether the device is connected to wifi or cell-service...when there is none it fires off the onOffline method. However if your are on wifi and lets say the router is down or your internet provider is unreachable it can't help you. Because you are "connected" to the wifi is treats this as "online". A combination of this answer and @Tushar answer should cover all bases.