# Unable to detect no internet connection, in cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have been searching on how to check internet connection for my cordova app(targeting android at the moment). I have tried the following:

```
 $.ajax("rss file url", {
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true
        })
               .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //get rss
               })
               .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  //no internet alert
               })
               .always(function () {
                   //alert("complete");
               });
```

Also I have tried

```
function doesConnectionExist() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = "file url";
    var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);

    xhr.open('HEAD', file + "?rand=" + randomNum, false);

    try {
        xhr.send();

        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (e) {
       return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that these work absolutely fine in visual studio's ripple emulators, but when I debug on android device I am getting always getting no connection result. Eventhough, the device is connected to wi-fi.
My app works fine if I remove this check. But, I need to check internet connectivity as my app is basically a rss feed reader. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143856/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-the-device-has-internet-access) I have already posted the $.ajax code. The problem is that the solution works fine on the ripple emulators. But when I release build on an android device from VS15, I keep getting no internet connection results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to check if the device has Internet access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143856/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-the-device-has-internet-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use

```
document.addEventListener("online", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

Then set some sort of variable to true in your callback function.

There's a same event for "offline".

This way you can also handle what happens if the user drops connection while using your app.

Source: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_events_events.md.html#online

Comment: Remember to wrap these functions inside a document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {}, false);

Comment: Thanks Steve..but i already tried this, but i had to dump it because the offline event was not firing in the device..which leads me to believe there is some other problem i just cant figure out what.

Comment: Hmm. In general, I think the "offline" event fires pretty well.  At least, that's been my experience.  However, I could see it being pretty device specific.  Meaning, the device might not quickly recognize the disconnection, and hence not fire down the API chain to cause the "offline".

Comment: anyways to overcome that?

Comment: Everything else seems "hacky".  But maybe something like this (also hacky): 

$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.google.com",
    context: document.body,
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        alert('offline')
    },
    success: function() {
        alert('ONline')
    }
}).  Except, instead of throwing alert, you could set a connection variable.

Comment: found the problem with the offline event, [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7787] 
Source[:http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/01/13/phonegap-onlineoffline-tip-2/]
The fix mentioned in the source although for something else worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used a JS Library called [OnlineJs](http://pixelscommander.com/polygon/onlinejs) and it works just fine to detect online and offline status.

try this link :

```
http://pixelscommander.com/polygon/onlinejs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function doesConnectionExist() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = "file url";
    var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
connection=getConnectionStatus();
if(connection){
 xhr.open('HEAD', file + "?rand=" + randomNum, false);

    try {
        xhr.send();

        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (e) {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Now inside the getConnectionStatus check for the connection.

```
   function getConnectionStatus() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
            var states = {};
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'unknown';
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'ethernet';
            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'wifi';
            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = '2g';
            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = '3g';
            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = '4g';
            states[Connection.CELL]     = 'cellular';
            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'none';
             if(networkState != 'none') { 
                   return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

    }
```

the states[] array is for undeerstanding as to what all types of network information u can manipulate with .

Hope it helps.